# Change select box options upon selecting option in first select box

Tags: javascript, html

In my javascript program I have created two select boxes and When the first option in the select box is selected,I want to display a selection of 3 images name in the images select box. When the second option is selected, I want to display a selection of corresponding 3 images name in the images box. For that I did below coding. but it's not working. can anyone help me to solve ?

code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>selectbox</title>
     <style>
    
     div.event {
      padding-left: 40%;
      padding-top: 5%;
     }
    
     #mySelect{
      width: 60px;
      height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="myForm">
     <div class="event">
      <select id="mySelect" multiple size="3" onchange="myFunction()">
       <option value="name" disabled="disabled">Name</option>
       <option value="animals">Animals</option>
       <option value="flowers">Flowers</option>
      </select>
    
      <select id="mySelect2" multiple size="4">
       <option disabled="disabled">Images</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </form>
    
    <script>
    
     var selectbox2 = document.getElementById('mySelect2');
    
     function myFunction() {
      if (document.getElementById('mySelect').value == "Animals"){
       selectbox2.append('<option>Tiger</option>');
       selectbox2.append('<option>Lion</option>');
       selectbox2.append('<option>Bear</option>');
      } 
    
      else if (document.getElementById('mySelect').value == "Flowers"){
       selectbox2.append('<option>Rose</option>');
       selectbox2.append('<option>Lotus</option>');
       selectbox2.append('<option>Lily</option>');
      }
     }
    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you have any errors in the Console?

Comment: Note that if you make this a code snippet we can actually run it here w/o having to go to JSFiddle/etc.

Comment: Unrelated, but it might just be easier to keep arrays of option value/text pairs and have a generic function to create the options instead of doing it all manually for each thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first select values are written in lower case, but your `if` tests are testing for capitals.

Second, the `append()` method is not standard and you should be using `.appendChild()` instead. But, with either one, you can't append strings. For strings, you must set the **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** property.

If you want to use `.append()` or `.appendChild()`, you need to be appending a "DOM node", which can be created like this:

```
 var option = document.create("option");
 option.value = "something";
```

Lastly, don't use inline HTML event attributes (`onclick`, `onchange`, etc.). **[There are many reasons why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)**. Instead do all your JavaScript work in a JavaScript area and follow modern standards for event handling (**[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>selectbox</title>
     <style>   
     div.event {
      padding-left: 40%;
      padding-top: 5%;
     }
    
     #mySelect{
      width: 60px;
      height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="myForm">
     <div class="event">
      <select id="mySelect" multiple size="3">
       <option value="name" disabled="disabled">Name</option>
       <option value="animals">Animals</option>
       <option value="flowers">Flowers</option>
      </select>
    
      <select id="mySelect2" multiple size="4">
       <option disabled="disabled">Images</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </form>
    
    <script>
    
      // Get a reference to the first drop down:
      var selectbox1 = document.getElementById('mySelect');
      
      // Set up the event handling for the first select:
      selectbox1.addEventListener("change", myFunction);
    
     var selectbox2 = document.getElementById('mySelect2');
    
     function myFunction() {
      if (document.getElementById('mySelect').value == "animals"){
       selectbox2.innerHTML = '<option disabled="disabled">Images</option><option>Tiger</option><option>Lion</option><option>Bear</option>';
      } 
    
      else if (document.getElementById('mySelect').value == "flowers"){
       selectbox2.innerHTML = '<option disabled="disabled">Images</option><option>Rose</option><option>Lotus</option><option>Lily</option>';
      }
     }
    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you. I've just added some simple feature.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>selectbox</title>
  <style>
    div.event {
      padding-left: 40%;
      padding-top: 5%;
    }
    
    #mySelect {
      width: 60px;
      height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="myForm">
    <div class="event">
      <select id="mySelect" multiple size="3" onchange="myFunction()">
       <option value="name" disabled="disabled">Name</option>
       <option value="animals">Animals</option>
       <option value="flowers">Flowers</option>
      </select>

      <select id="mySelect2" multiple size="4">
       <option disabled="disabled">Images</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>

  <script>
    var selectbox2 = document.getElementById('mySelect2');

    function myFunction() {
      if (document.getElementById('mySelect').value == "animals") {
        selectbox2.options.length = 1;
        let tiger = document.createElement('option');
        tiger.text = 'Tiger';
        selectbox2.add(tiger);
        let lion = document.createElement('option');
        lion.text = 'Lion';
        selectbox2.add(lion);
        let bear = document.createElement('option');
        bear.text = 'Bear';
        selectbox2.add(bear);
      } else if (document.getElementById('mySelect').value == "flowers") {
        selectbox2.options.length = 1;
        let rose = document.createElement('option');
        rose.text = 'Rose';
        selectbox2.add(rose);
        let lotas = document.createElement('option');
        lotas.text = 'Lotas';
        selectbox2.add(lotas);
        let lilly = document.createElement('option');
        lilly.text = 'Lilly';
        selectbox2.add(lilly);
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```